# For loop doesn't iterate through the whole variable, instead it only performs the functionality only for the first value. Why?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I'm trying to delete the todos in the Map data-type (todoDate) I have created.
**the Map<String, List> data type variable problem (todoDate) problem:**
I want every key in the Map to be deleted but instead what happens is that only the key with index 0 is deleted and the rest remain. Thanks for helping.

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid.toString(); 
final todo =
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(uid).collection('todos');

void Function()? deleteTodoCollection(Map<String, List<String>> todoDate) {
  //delete from firebase
  todo.get().then((snapshot) {
    for (DocumentSnapshot doc in snapshot.docs) {
      doc.reference.delete();
    }
  });

  //delete from the todoDate map
  for (var key in todoDate.keys) { 
    todoDate.remove(key);
    print(todoDate);
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: `print(todoDate.keys)` somewhere to see what it actually is

Comment: I did write print(todoDate) which shows both its keys and values, its the same if i do todoDate.keys

Comment: Generally removing elements from the collection you're iterating over will break iteration.  Usually that should result in a [`ConcurrentModificationError`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/ConcurrentModificationError-class.html) being thrown.  If you don't observe such an error, I suspect that you have an unqualified `catch (e) { ... }` block in the call chain that is swallowing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try toList()

```
...
for (var key in todoDate.keys.toList()) {
...
```

Comment: Code-only answers that don't explain *why* an answer works encourage cargo cult programming.  See [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73234671/#comment129346692_73234671) for why `.toList()` probably fixes this.